# Routing issues in Rails when a Blog component was added

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The app was working fine until we added a blog. Then, we started having some routing issues. Every link on the navbar still works fine, including the blog link, which opens the index of of all the posts. When you click on one of the links to go to a specific post, the page displays, as it should. But, in order for a user to make a comment, he/she needs to login or signup. So, we put two links  on the page. The problem is when you click on one of these links, or any other link on the navbar, you get an error message, a typical message is as follows:

Couldn't find Post with id=login

At this point, we are not at the root anymore. In this instance, the address bar reads:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/login
```

The only way to get to the root is by clicking a ‘Back’ link on the page , which takes the user back to the Blog index page.

This is what my routes file looks like:

```
Septactus::Application.routes.draw do  
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users, :path => "auth", :path_names => { 
                                                   :sign_in => 'login', 
                                                   :sign_out => 'logout', 
                                                   :password => 'secret', 
                                                   :confirmation => 'verification', 
                                                   :unlock => 'unblock', 
                                                   :registration => 'register', 
                                                   :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' 
                                                  }
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}

 match '/home',         :to => 'site_pages#home'
 match '/about',        :to => 'site_pages#about'
 match '/bookshelf',    :to => 'books#index'
 match '/blog',         :to => 'posts#index'
 match '/icasts',       :to => 'site_pages#icasts'
 match '/portfolio',    :to => 'site_pages#portfolio'

 devise_scope :user do 
   match "login",   :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
   match 'logout',  :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
   match 'signup',  :to => 'devise/registrations#create'
 end

 resources :site_pages
 resources :books
 resources :users
 resources :posts do
  resources :comments
 end

 root :to => 'site_pages#home'

end
```

Any clue, anyone?

Comment: Please show the view code that is generating the link to `posts/login`

Comment: See my next post for the view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this issue. And here is the solution for those who might come across it in the future:

As everyone knows, Rails routing uses controller#action to specify a route to a page: for instance: pages#home

If you go beyond the boundaries of the controller (in this instance ‘pages’), which is the root, to get to another page/link on another controller, for example a posts' controller and try to reach a page on the ‘pages’ controller, such as in:

```
     http://localhost:3000/posts/about
```

you’ll get an error. That's because the routes.rb does not contain a path to that link from where you are, so you have to tell it how to get there. That is exactly what I did:

Here are the routes (untouched) for the site_pages' controller: [http://localhost:3000]

```
match '/home',         :to => 'site_pages#home'
match '/about',        :to => 'site_pages#about'
match '/bookshelf',    :to => 'books#index'
match '/blog',         :to => 'posts#index'
match '/icasts',       :to => 'site_pages#icasts'
match '/portfolio',    :to => 'site_pages#portfolio'
```

Here are the new routes for the posts' controller requested from this controller: http://localhost:3000/posts/[id]/

```
match "/posts/home(.:format)"      => "site_pages#home", :as      => :home
match "/posts/about(.:format)"     => "site_pages#about", :as     => :about
match "/posts/bookshelf(.:format)" => "books#index", :as          => :bookshelf
match "/posts/blog(.:format)"      => "posts#index",   :as        => :blog
match "/posts/icasts(.:format)"    => "site_pages#icasts", :as    => :icasts
match "/posts/portfolio(.:format)" => "site_pages#portfolio",:as  => :portfolio
```

And here are the routes to Devise ‘login’, ‘logout’, and ‘signup’ links going from the posts' controller (the last 3 lines):

```
devise_scope :user do 
  match "login",          :to  => 'devise/sessions#new'
  match 'logout',         :to  => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  match 'signup',         :to  => 'devise/registrations#create'
  match "/posts/login",   :to  => "devise/sessions#new"
  match "/posts/logout",  :to  => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  match "/posts/signup",  :to  => "devise/sessions#create"
end
```

NB. If Devise links are not wrapped within the Devise scope, Rails will return an error.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem in this line:

```
<p>To add a comment, <%= link_to 'Login', 'login' %> or <%= link_to 'Signup', "signup" %></p>
```

you need to change to

```
<p>To add a comment, <%= link_to 'Login', login_path %> or <%= link_to 'Signup', signup_path %></p>
```

Comment: No. That didn't work. In fact, it got worse. I couldn't even access any of my posts. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Can you please share your view?

Comment: You can view the code view here:                                                                                             http://jsfiddle.net/adam0964/VLNhs

Comment: We have a partial header that holds the website Menu, including the Login link and it is configured the way you suggested  <%= link_to 'Signup', signup_path %>.                                             This is not the only link we're having a problem with, it's every link we try to go to from:                                     http://localhost:3000/posts/[post_d]/[home/about/blog.....]